Migrating Spring WAR application to Spring Boot
I have a Spring application that runs as a WAR file in a standalone servlet container, by having a class that extends SpringBootServletInitializer, which is called by the servlet container.
I would like to be able to run the application using the Spring Boot embedded servlet container, rather than have to create a WAR and deploy it into my standalone servlet container.
I tried creating a class that has the @SpringBootAppliation annotation and calls SpringApplication.run(...).  However, this ends up throwing exceptions which I think are to do with the application starting before the servlet container.
As such, I was wondering if it was possible to start the embedded servlet container and run my application as if it was running in the standalone servlet container, e.g. have the servlet container call the SpringBootServletInitialiser
Regards,
Carl

For this migration you need to modify the pom.xml as well. For example by removing scope/provided from the tomcat dependency. Please try it and provide the current sources and log files.

Below is a proof of concept test,
Things to verify:



Spring Boot is executed in jar form




Test that the Web Servlet can be executed




Test that Spring MVC JSP can be executed



Project Tree:
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           ├── DemoJspApplication.java
        │           ├── ServletInitializer.java(*)       
        │           ├── HelloJSPController.java
        │           └── HelloServlet.java
        ├── resources
        │   ├── logback.xml
        │   └── application.properties
        └── webapp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── jsp
                    └── hello.jsp

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-no-war-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-no-war-jsp</name>
    <description>Demo No War JSP project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

application.properties
spring.application.name=hello-jsp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

logback.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %-50logger{40} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
     
    <appender name="RollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>app.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %-50logger{40} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
         
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>10MB</totalSizeCap>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
     
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
</configuration>

DemoJspApplication.java
package com.example;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletComponentScan;


@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoJspApplication {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoJspApplication.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info(">>>DemoJspApplication START");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoJspApplication.class, args);
        logger.info(">>>DemoJspApplication END");
    }

}

HelloServlet.java
package com.example;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

@WebServlet("/hello2")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloServlet.class);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HelloServlet() {
        super();
        logger.info(">>>HelloServlet()");
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        
        response.getWriter().write("Hello from HelloServlet at " + currentDateTime);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}

HelloJSPController.java
package com.example;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class HelloJSPController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloJSPController.class);

    public HelloJSPController(){
       super();
       logger.info(">>>>HelloJSPController()");
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hellojsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello(Map<String, Object> model) {

        logger.info("HelloJSP Controller hello");

        model.put("message", "HelloJSP Controller hello");

        // /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp
        return new ModelAndView("hello");
    }
}

ServletInitializer.java
Note: It is not initialized or called.
package com.example;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServletInitializer.class);

        public ServletInitializer(){
           super();
           logger.info(">>>ServletInitializer()");
        }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            logger.info(">>>ServletInitializer configure");
        return application.sources(DemoJspApplication.class);
    }

}

hello.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello</title>
    <style>
        .color-red {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<%
// debug
System.out.println("webapp / WEB-INF / jsp / hello.jsp ");
%>
<body>
   <h1 class="color-red">SpringBoot hello.jsp!!  ${message} </h1>
</body>
</html>

Build
mvn clean package

Run
java -jar target/demo-no-war-jsp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Console output
2024-08-17 10:55:11,208 [main] INFO  com.example.DemoJspApplication                     - >>>DemoJspApplication START

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.2)

2024-08-17 10:55:11,653 [main] INFO  com.example.DemoJspApplication                     - Starting DemoJspApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.11 with PID 4985 (/home/demo/Documents/Examples_SpringBoot/demo-no-war-jsp/target/demo-no-war-jsp.jar started by demo in /home/demo/Documents/Examples_SpringBoot/demo-no-war-jsp)
2024-08-17 10:55:11,655 [main] INFO  com.example.DemoJspApplication                     - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-08-17 10:55:12,422 [main] INFO  o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer            - Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-08-17 10:55:12,431 [main] INFO  o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol           - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2024-08-17 10:55:12,433 [main] INFO  o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService             - Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-08-17 10:55:12,433 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine            - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.26]
2024-08-17 10:55:12,635 [main] INFO  org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner               - At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2024-08-17 10:55:12,677 [main] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]                 - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-08-17 10:55:12,677 [main] INFO  o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext     - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 947 ms
2024-08-17 10:55:12,682 [main] INFO  com.example.HelloServlet                           - >>>HelloServlet()
2024-08-17 10:55:12,739 [main] INFO  com.example.HelloJSPController                     - >>>>HelloJSPController()
2024-08-17 10:55:12,955 [main] INFO  o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol           - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2024-08-17 10:55:12,979 [main] INFO  o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer            - Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-08-17 10:55:12,992 [main] INFO  com.example.DemoJspApplication                     - Started DemoJspApplication in 1.694 seconds (process running for 2.173)
2024-08-17 10:55:12,994 [main] INFO  com.example.DemoJspApplication                     - >>>DemoJspApplication END

NOTE: ServletInitializer not output anything. This means it has not been initialized or called.
You can add corresponding logs to the constructor and method entries to check whether the class is started or called.
Web Test

Test Web Servlet http://localhost:8080/hello2
Test Spring MVC JSP http://localhost:8080/hellojsp

